# Profile provisioning error when deploying to device in release mode

Tags: iphone

When I build and deploy to my device in debug mode, everything works fine.
But when I switch to release mode I get an error:

> Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '' can't be found

And indeed, I have no idea where or why xcode is looking for this profile.
Based on what I have read it seems I have to delete all profiles and create a new one just for a release build.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Sounds like an iPhone question -- you should probably add the "iphone" tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at the settings for your target (opt-cmd-e), change to the "Release" configuration (dropdown box in the top left) and take a look at what the "Code Signing Identity" is set to under the "Code Signing" section.  Try changing it to a different one and see if it works.

Comment: I noticed that when i change the setting in the configuration (dropdown box in the top left) other settings related to that does NOT get changed.

Example: Let's say i change it to "iphone-simulator debug".
Then I would expect to see the "Base SDK" setting to change to simulator as well. But this is NOT the case.

In short, to make a build setting change, i need to make such changes in more than one location.

Ugh. How sloppy and silly. Please tell me i dont have to do this!